# Console app that opens a new window for each thread started by background worker

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, console-application

I have a console application that starts multiple different threads. The main console app will poll a service and based on responses it will spawn one or more background threads using the BackgroundWorker class. At the moment each of these threads do a console.writeline to the sole  default console window opened as it normally does for a console application. This makes it too confusing to follow the progress of any one thread.

I want to be able to spawn a separate window with each of them writing their own console.writeline() to their own windows. When done, the main console app window will close the spawned console window, and then start it up again when it needs to.

I have not been able to find anything useful on this online. Im probably not using the correct keywords in my search. Any help in this please?

Comment: If this was WPF I would have each a Window and each Windows starts its own BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I dont have any starting point for creating new windows as part of the background worker process. The code I have right now shows everything in the same window and it works properly. I am trying to add this new feature so dont have any code for that as yet..

Comment: @blam: you mean in a MDI scenario?

Comment: It looks that it is impossible: `A process can be associated with only one console` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Add thread ID to all output lines and filter output to see every thread results.

Comment: new window or new console??

Comment: MDI is not WPF term.   You can start multiple Windows and each has it own code behind.

Comment: @AlexFarber, further in that same page, you could manually switch between consoles using FreeConsole() and AttachConsole().  It'll be a mess I'm sure!...

Comment: Try using colored output to console from different threads. There are `Console.ForegroundColor` and `Console.BackgroundColor` properties.

Comment: @giammin: a console window

Comment: @VladimirFrolov: thats some interim relief.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a separate console window for each thread. There can be only one console per process.
 You may want to look at this thread [thread having its own console](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f0398ca8-104f-42fe-a9a3-bf8c6105e4bc/thread-having-its-own-console)

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to Vladimir's comments there's a nice sample app here that demonstrates attaching and detaching from a console and changing the display colors and locations and has some c# libraries build around the Windows Console API.

http://www.mischel.com/diary/2006/08/19.htm