# Cleanest way to update user on thread status in multithreaded console application

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, logging, console-application

I have a console application that I have recently made multithreaded. My hope was that I could open up the thread in a new console window, but according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381696/console-app-that-opens-a-new-window-for-each-thread-started-by-background-worker), it isn't really possible/advisable to do such a thing.

I have the following:

```
do
{
      selection = DisplayMenu();

      switch (selection)
      {
          case 1:
              Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Method1(param1, param2, param3));
              thread1.Start();
              break;
          case 2:
              Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => Method2(param1, param2, param3));
              thread2.Start();
              break;
          default:
               break;
       }      
} while (selection != 3);
```

`Method1` and `Method2` both have `Console.WriteLine()` calls that display messages to the console window indicating to the user what steps have completed, what step is currently running etc. Everything works, except for the fact that when `DisplayMenu()` gets displayed after the first thread is run, it kind of gets pushed to the top because of the `Console` logging that the methods in the `switch` statement do, hence why I originally wanted to off load the thread to another console window. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

This is what `DisplayMenu()` does:

```
public static int DisplayMenu()
{
    int selection = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("[1] X");
    Console.WriteLine("[2] Y");
    Console.WriteLine("[3] QUIT");
    Console.Write("Selection: ");
    selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();

    return selection ;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Per the accepted answer, I am now trying to route my `Console.WriteLine()` calls to a Windows Form instead. I have added all needed dependencies and a Windows Form to my console project. This is what I have so far.

```
public static void WorkToDo()
{
    MyCustomObj myObj = new MyCustomObject();

    var form = new OutputForm();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    form.Controls.Add(tb);
    form.Show(); //Code does not progress until window is closed

    if (MyCustomObject.Validate())
    {
        tb.Text += "Sent from Console App!"; //This was previously my Console.WriteLine() call.
```

Seems that I can't stream to the `TextBox` since the process is now running the form and not the rest of the code in the console application.

Comment: What is `DisplayMenu`?

Comment: If you need such a complicated console system, you may want to look at setting the cursor to the bottom of the window and outputting status data there, then resetting the cursor back to the main part of the window for everything else. Lock on a synchronization object to keep only one process writing to the window at a time. There are ways though to open more console windows if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to do this?

If you do not need to debug the second thread/console or share resources you could use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("*.exe");` to launch an additional console window, however I am guessing that is not what you want?

You may be better off using a GUI such as WPF or Windows Forms with multiple windows, one for the logging and another for the user input? Or possibly logging to a file?

It is possible to have a child process hosting another console window. This is detailed here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13368/Multiple-consoles-for-a-single-application

Create a windows forms project and use the GUI tools to add the text box etc. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx for more.
Then edit the code behind the form like so:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StreamTextExample
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Threading;

    internal sealed partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var timer = new BackgroundWorker();
            timer.DoWork += DoWork;
            timer.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                var del = new AddText(AddTextCallback);
                Invoke(del, string.Format("{0} seconds have passed.\r\n", i));

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void AddTextCallback(string value)
        {
            textBox1.Text += value;
        }

        private delegate void AddText(string value);
    }
}
```

Given a button (button1) and a text box (textBox1) this will add the seconds passed since button1 is pressed (up to 9) to the text box.

Comment: Additionally, the reason this was not so easy is that there's only one of each standard streams (input, output and error) per process.

Comment: William, I am accepting your answer per your suggestion to use Windows Form. I am currently trying to launch a windows form window and stream text into there. Can you provide any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example using windows forms.

I can add additional explanations if you wish

Comment: @WilliamMoore I have added a Windows Form to my console application and am now just trying to write straight to that. Is this possible?

`var form = new OutputForm();
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
form.Controls.Add(tb);
form.Show(); //Gets stuck here
tb.Text += "write to textbox instead of console";`

Comment: Have you initialized your text box's `.Text` property.
Your first use of the text box will have to be like this:
`TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = "";
// Add text box...then use +=`

Also if you access the text box form an other thread from the one which created it, you must use the delegate callback (as I displayed above).